# Using LINQ in Wolfram

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, wolfram-mathematica

We have an IEnumerable Objects in C# that we want to import into the Wolfram Financial Platform. In the current C# API, we use LINQ queries to select from the Objects the specific Object that we need. In Wolfram Financial Platform we can import the IEnumerable Objects through NET/Link (More info: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/Overview.html)

Once the object is imported, there does not seem to be a way to use LINQ queries even after importing the LINQ library. Additionally, lambda expressions used in the LINQ queries do not have a clear replacement in Wolfram Financial Platform. They have something similar called "pure functions".

**Examples**

C#

```
Object.Where(x => x.Property == Target).FirstOrDefault();
```

Wolfram

```
???[# == #.Property &, Object]`FirstOrDefault[];
```

**Current Attempt + Error**

C#

```
client.GetMarketDataSnapshots(optionChain.Options.Select(x => x as Security).ToList());
```

Wolfram

```
client@GetMarketDataSnapshots[
   Map[CastNETObject[#, 
      "Core.Data.Securities.Security"] &, 
    optionChain@Options]];
```

Error

```
NET::netexcptn: "A .NET exception occurred: "System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.Data.Securities.Option]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.Data.Securities.Security]'."
```

**End Goal**

Import specific values from a C# API with LINQ queries, or equivalent, intact into Wolfram Financial Platform for the purpose of writing a program in the Wolfram Financial Platform language (not allowed to do it the other way around, as much as I want to).

Comment: I would get an xml response from wolfram and then use xml linq.  Do a web search for "wolfram xml response"

Comment: Look at this webpage : http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, however getting an xml response from Wolfram to process in C# to then process back in Wolfram would be the beginning of a delicious spaghetti that I don't want to get tangled in. I revised my question to give a better idea of what the end goal is, which is to find replacements for lambda expressions and LINQ queries within Wolfram for working with the C# API through NET/Link.

Comment: Once you get xml from wolfram you can parse the xmlin c# and send back values to wolfram in any format you like.  The return values to wolfram doesn't have to be xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that you are trying to pass a list of `Core.Data.Securities.Option` to a list of `Core.Data.Securities.Security`.  Since `Core.Data.Securities.Option` does not inherit/implement `Core.Data.Securities.Security`, you cannot cast it.

Your code:

```
client@GetMarketDataSnapshots[
Map[CastNETObject[#, 
    "Core.Data.Securities.Security"] &, 
optionChain@Options]];
```

Should be changed to:

```
client@GetMarketDataSnapshots[
Map[CastNETObject[#, 
    "Core.Data.Securities.Option"] &, 
optionChain@Options]];
```

This will cast the `optionChain@Options` object to a `Core.Data.Securities.Option` (which is what it really is).

**Update After Comment:**

The documentation states that ["the vast majority of casts you see in .NET programs are irrelevant in .NET/Link."](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromTheWolframLanguage.html#16712) with the exceptions "working with COM objects" and "upcasts".

Assuming that you are upcasting instances of `Core.Data.Securities.Option` to `Core.Data.Securities.Security`, what you did should work, as long as all of the Option instances are really Security instances.

Your C# code uses the `as` keyword which will try to cast the variable to the desired type, returning `null` when it fails.   [`CastNETObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/ref/CastNETObject.html) does not say anything about doing this.  In C#, it would be equivalent to `client.GetMarketDataSnapshots(optionChain.Options.Select(x => (Security)x).ToList());`.

What you need is to check the datatype with [`InstanceOf`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/ref/InstanceOf.html) and only cast the objects which are compatible with `Security`.  I think it would look something like this in Wolfram (*code updated to show final solution*):

```
options = 
    NETNew["System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.Data.Securities.Security]"];

Scan[options@
    Add[CastNETObject[#, 
        "Core.Data.Securities.Security"]] &, 
    optionChain@Options@ToArray[]];
```

In case I did it wrong, here it is in C# syntax (so you can convert it yourself):

```
client.GetMarketDataSnapshots(optionChain.Options.Select(x => (x.GetType() == typeof(Security)) ? (Security)x : null).ToList());
```

**Update on Performance (from comments):**

As for the performance, there probably is not a faster method. Wolfram is focused on ease of use and solving math problems. The fact that it even interfaces with .NET is surprising. Your options (as I see them) are contacting support to see if there is a faster system or they can fix things, or making a .NET method to either convert the list or wrap the function so only the correct types are returned.

Comment: I need to cast the list of Core.Data.Securities.Option to a list of Core.Data.Securities.Security for the GetMarketDataSnapshots parameter.

Comment: @user1981756  I have updated my answer.  You may want to update your question to include the information in your comment.

Comment: This was pretty close. It worked with a few modifications: removing LoadNETType, creating a separate variable options = NETNew["System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.Data.Securities.Security]", using options@Add[Cast..., and optionChain@Options@ToArray[]. However, it is extremely slow. It takes about 41 seconds to finish. There has to be a faster way to cast the elements of a .NET list in Wolfram.

Comment: @user1981756  Go ahead and edit my answer with the corrected code and add a comment indicating that this is the code you used.  For the Edit Summary, make sure you mention that we talked in the comments (so it will get past review).  The go ahead and [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @user1981756 As for the performance, there probably is not a faster method.  Wolfram is focused on ease of use and solving math problems.  The fact that it even interfaces with .NET is surprising.  Your options (as I see them) are contacting support to see if there is a faster system or they can fix things, or making a .NET method to either convert the list or wrap the function so only the correct results are returned.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. There may be another way, but it seems the updated solution above is the best that can be done for casting a .NET List in Wolfram. That in mind, knowing where the weaknesses and strengths of the language are was a valuable learning experience. To get around the limitation, I created a helper class in C# to handle casting the list. Went from 41 seconds casting the list to .005 seconds! [Outlined it here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110821/optimizing-casting-objects-of-a-net-list-object)